# NFC enabled phone act as a NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

I have seen many questions on SO about NFC, the closest question I have come across is [Can an Android NFC phone act as an NFC tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138077/can-an-android-nfc-phone-act-as-an-nfc-tag)

However that question was asked over a year ago when the Galaxy Nexus wasn't even announced yet, nor Android 4.0 +, now at the end of 2012 I have a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.1 (Stock). I know how to read NFC tags and get the data etc from them, but is it possible now to replicate the tag and use the phone to act as the tag.

An example of this will be the following:

- I have a bus card, which basically just holds an identity, when I scan the card it pays for my bus ticket along with adding cash to it etc.
- It would rather handy if I could just copy the data to my phone, then when ever I go onto the bus, instead of using a tag, just use phone and write it to the reader.

Comment: I think this question also covers yours: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11831651/27190.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an Android NFC phone act as an NFC tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138077/can-an-android-nfc-phone-act-as-an-nfc-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.2.1 as well as earlier versions do not support card emulation or any similar features.